# How can I create a CRUD method in a model using Loopback?

Tags: node.js, express, loopback

I have to add a delete method in a Loopback project and I never touched something about Loopback. I know express and NodeJS but loopback? → Zero

But I know that you can create models with a Wizard and this models comes with all the methods (PUT, POST, GET, UPDATE, DELETE, ...), but the proyect that i'm trying to edit, the model "Registry" just have 1 method POST, i need the method Delete I think, how can get that?

I'm searching the docs and other pages, but I found nothing :/ 
Any solution?
Thanks in advance!

I tried with remote methdos but i got this error:

```
Unhandled error for request GET /Attendant/api/v1/registries/greet?msg=test: Error: Shared class "registry" has no method handling GET /greet?msg=test
```

And this is my code in registry.js

```
....
Registry.greet = function(msg, cb) {
    cb(null, 'Greetings... ' + msg);
}

Registry.remoteMethod('greet', {
    accepts: { arg: 'msg', type: 'string' },
    returns: { arg: 'greeting', type: 'string' }
});
....
```

And in mu registry.json:

```
...
    "methods": {
        "getHour": {
            "accepts": [],
            "returns": {
                "arg": "data",
                "root": true
            },
            "http": {
                "verb": "get",
                "path": "/hours/current"
            }
        },
        "createRegistry": {
            "accepts": [{
                "arg": "req",
                "type": "object",
                "required": true,
                "http": {
                    "source": "req"
                }
            }],
            "returns": {
                "arg": "data",
                "root": true
            },
            "http": {
                "verb": "post",
                "path": "/"
            }
        },
        "greet": {
            "http": {
                "verb": "get",
                "path": "/greet"
            }
        }
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you need in order to add a 'Greet' remote method.

```
Registry.greet = function(msg, cb) {
   cb(null, 'Greetings... ' + msg);
}

Registry.remoteMethod('greet', {
   http: { path: '/greet', method: 'get' },
   accepts: { arg: 'msg', type: 'string', http: { source: 'query' } },
   returns: { arg: 'greeting', type: 'string' }
});
```

You don't need to change anything in the JSON model reference.